# Mage registry key "_singleton/econnect/observer" already exists

Tags: magento-1.9

Need Help,

I am new to Magento, I am using **Magento 1.9**, **I have installed **EbizCahrge** Module manually via FTP**. After uploading all files now I am unable to access site admin panel.

when I am trying to access admin panel it's showing me this error.

```
**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1196662910737**
```

I have checked error in var/report file.
File showing me these errors.

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:63:"Mage registry key "_singleton/econnect/observer" already exists";i:1;s:3766:"
#0 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/econ...', false)
#2 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('econnect/observ...')
#3 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(887): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form.additional...', true)
#9 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml(61): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('form.additional...')
#10 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/da...')
#11 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#19 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#20 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#21 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#22 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /chroot/home/daymotor/dev.daymotorsports.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

#26{main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/index.php/daymotor_admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were installing the module when compilation was enabled.

Now you need to switch off the module in app/etc/modules by renaming the .xml file, then clear the cache by renaming the var/cache folder. The admin panel will become active and you’ll have to disable compilation and then install the module once again. Hope it will help.

OR

you can

1)Clear cache and session
2)Find this folder in the package: /step_1/app/design/frontend/base/default/ ; copy its content to mysite/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/
Find this folder in the package: /step_1/skin/frontend/base/default/ ; copy its content to mysite/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/
3) Copy the content of /Step_2/ folder to your store's root directory (that is mysite)
4)clear cache and session